# Have subdirectory name act as $_GET or $_POST data

Tags: pages, htaccess, directory

I have a page with a list of items that I want to have my users cycle through without a page load happening between each item. This works. However, I also want each item to have it's own URL. I'm using this snippet to have the browser change the url when a user clicks on a certain item:

```
if (typeof history.pushState != 'undefined') {
    var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
    history.replaceState(stateObj, "", "/mypage/" + prop.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + "/");
}
```

What I also want is for when someone goes to those faked URLs, any subpage of `/mypage/` will be sent as `$_GET` or `$_POST` data.

What is the best way to do this? I am aware that I can write something in my .htaccess file, but is there another way to do this that I can plug into my `functions.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you know -- there's a plugin for that: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Under the "redirects" tab in the plugin's settings you can set as many redirect rules as you'd like.